# Highcharts png export pie

Tags: highcharts, export, png, fill

I am trying to export a pie chart (via export.highcharts.com) containing a radialised fill. I can get the chart to render correctly on screen but upon export the chart does not retain the radial fill, the exported chart contains flat colours. Does the Highcharts export server have this capability or am I missing something obvious?

```
var exportUrl = 'http://export.highcharts.com/';
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
$.each(colors, function(i, color) {
  colors[i] = {
    radialGradient: {
      cx: 0.5,
      cy: 0.3,
      r: 0.7
    },
    stops: [
      [0, color],
      [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
    ]
  };

});

var optionsStr = JSON.stringify({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'Varela Round',
        fontSize: '24px'
      },
      text: 'Dashboard Logon Activity by User'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },

    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: 'Units'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        //center: [960, 450],
        size: 200,
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
          style: {
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
            fontFamily: 'Varela Round',
            fontSize: '10px'
          },
          connectorColor: 'silver'
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'logons',
      data: [{
        "name": "User 1",
        "y": 19
      }, {
        "name": "User 2",
        "y": 16
      }, {
        "name": "User 3",
        "y": 22
      }, {
        "name": "User 4",
        "y": 8
      }, {
        "name": "User 5",
        "y": 31
      }, {
        "name": "User 6",
        "y": 17
      }],
      color: colors
    }]
  }),
  globalOptions = JSON.stringify({
    lang: {
      thousandsSep: ','
    }
  }),
  dataString = encodeURI('async=true&type=jpeg&width=1200&options=' + optionsStr + '&globalOptions=' + globalOptions);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: dataString,
  url: exportUrl,
  success: function(data) {
    //console.log('get the file from http://export.highcharts.com/: ', data);
    //$('#container').html('<img src="' + exportUrl + data + '"/>');
    var imageurl = exportUrl + data;
    console.log(imageurl);
  },
  error: function(err) {
    debugger;
    console.log('error', err.statusText)
  }

});
```

**Radialised output from application**:

[image: Radialised output from application]

**Exported image with flat fill:**

[image: Exported image with flat fill]

Comment: I just tried from the demo pie [link](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-gradient) and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, but for my scenario I need to initiate the export automatically and the output is to be further processed server side. The chart is required (to go with other data) into a PDF report via php so this is just the first step.

Comment: The problem you are having is because of a typo. You need to use `colors: colors` and **not** `color: colors` in your series definition. Fixing this, it works. See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/qgpjthL9/4/

Comment: Thank you very much ewolden for your help.  I soo hate myself right now...